# Rewrite this recurrence relation to an explicit formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We have the recurrence relation $x_n = x_{n-1} - x_{n-2}$ with $x_0 =1$ and $x_1 = 1$. How exactly can I write this to explicit form? There doesn't seem to be a general method.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearRecurrenceEquation.html

Comment: @5xum It is subtracting, not adding, as shown in your link.  I don't think the solution is in your link.

Comment: @SimpleArt Set $A=1$, $B=-1$ in the equation $x_n = Ax_{n-1} + Bx_{n-2}$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If you are not already familiar with complex numbers, please forgive me since , in such a case, I should be totally off topic.*

The recurrence relation being $$x_n = x_{n-1} - x_{n-2}$$ its characteristic equation is $$r^2=r-1$$ Using the classical formula for quadratic equation, the roots are $r_{1,2}=\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}$. So $$x_n=c_1\, r_1^n+c_2 \,r_2^n$$ But $r_{1,2}=\cos(\frac \pi 3)\pm i\sin(\frac \pi 3)=e^{\pm \frac {i\pi} 3}$ which make $$x_n=c_1\,\left(e^{ \frac {i\pi} 3}\right)^n+c_2\,\left(e^{ -\frac {i\pi} 3}\right)^n=c_1\,e^{ i\frac {n\pi} 3}+c_2\,e^{ -i\frac {n\pi} 3}$$ $$x_n=c_1\left(\cos(n \frac \pi 3)+i\sin(n \frac \pi 3)\right)+c_2\left(\cos(n \frac \pi 3)-i\sin(n \frac \pi 3)\right)$$ Now, apply the conditions $$x_0=c_1+c_2=1$$ $$x_1=c_1\left(\cos( \frac \pi 3)+i\sin( \frac \pi 3)\right)+c_2\left(\cos( \frac \pi 3)-i\sin( \frac \pi 3)\right)=\frac 12(c_1+c_2)+i\frac{\sqrt 3} 2(c_1-c_2)=1$$ and solve for $c_1,c_2$. This will give $$c_1=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2 \sqrt{3}}\qquad c_2=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2 \sqrt{3}}$$ So, $$x_n=\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2 \sqrt{3}}\right)\left(\cos(n \frac \pi 3)+i\sin(n \frac \pi 3)\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2 \sqrt{3}}\right)\left(\cos(n \frac \pi 3)-i\sin(n \frac \pi 3)\right)$$ Expand and simplify to get $$x_n=\cos \left(n\frac{\pi 
   }{3}\right)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\sin \left(n\frac{\pi  }{3}\right)$$ and then the sequence Brian M. Scott showed in his anwer.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Sometimes *very* elementary methods work just fine. It never hurts to gather some numerical data:

$$\begin{array}{rcc}
n:&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12\\
x_n:&1&1&0&-1&-1&0&\color{orange}1&\color{orange}1&\color{orange}0&\color{orange}{-1}&\color{orange}{-1}&\color{orange}0&1
\end{array}$$

Now make the natural conjecture, and prove it by induction.